Handles mouseMoveEvent for a QGraphicsItem object after calling the context menu
I have an implementation of the Square class based on QGraphicsItem. The class is implemented in such a way that I could move the object on the QGraphicsView.
Next, I create a context menu for the Square object in the GraphicsView class. The problem is that after I click on a menu item, and then on an arbitrary area of the scene with the left mouse button, the object on which I clicked moves to this place. Although this shouldn't happen. How to solve this problem?
class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GraphicsView(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
        : QGraphicsView(parent)
    {
        setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
        connect(this, &GraphicsView::customContextMenuRequested, this, &GraphicsView::showContextMenu);

        scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        scene->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::white);
        setScene(scene);

        auto square = new Square();
        square->setPos(10, 10);
        scene->addItem(square);

        auto square2 = new Square();
        square2->setPos(50, 50);
        scene->addItem(square2);
    }
    ~GraphicsView() override = default;

    void showContextMenu(const QPoint& pos)
    {
        auto position = QPoint(pos);

        QGraphicsItem* item = scene->itemAt(mapToScene(pos), QTransform());
        if (item && dynamic_cast<Square*>(item))
        {
            QMenu contextMenu(tr("Context menu1"), this);

            QAction addBt1(tr("Btn1"), this);
            connect(&addBt1, &QAction::triggered, this, &GraphicsView::addBtn1);
            contextMenu.addAction(&addBt1);

            QAction addBtn2(tr("Btn2"), this);
            connect(&addBtn2, &QAction::triggered, this, &GraphicsView::addBtn2);
            contextMenu.addAction(&addBtn2);

            contextMenu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
        }
    }

    static void addBtn1()
    {
        qDebug() << "Btn1";
    }

    static void addBtn2()
    {
        qDebug() << "Btn2";
    }
    
    QGraphicsScene* scene;
};

class Square : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Square(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent), QGraphicsItem() {}
    ~Square() {}

private:
    QRectF boundingRect() const override { return {-3,-3,6,6}; }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override
    {
        painter->setPen(Qt::black);
        painter->setBrush(Qt::green);
        painter->drawSquare(-3,-3,6,6);
        Q_UNUSED(option);
        Q_UNUSED(widget);
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        auto newPosition = mapToScene(event->pos());
        QPointF positionMirrorDifference = newPosition - this->pos();
        this->setPos(newPosition);
    }
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override { Q_UNUSED(event); }
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event) override { Q_UNUSED(event); }
};

Upd. I also tried moving the menu implementation to the Square class.
A similar problem remains. You can reproduce it if you first move the object, then call up the menu, click on the menu item, then hold down the mouse button in the arbitary location of the GraphicsView and move the mouse. After this, the object will also change position, despite the fact that the mouse was not pressed on it.
class Square : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Square(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent), QGraphicsItem()
    { setFlag(ItemIsMovable); }
    ~Square(){}

private:
    QRectF boundingRect() const override { return {-3,-3,6,6}; }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override
    {
        painter->setPen(Qt::black);
        painter->setBrush(Qt::green);
        painter->drawRect(-3,-3,6,6);
        Q_UNUSED(option);
        Q_UNUSED(widget);
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
            QMenu contextMenu;
            QAction *action1 = contextMenu.addAction("Action 1");
            QAction *action2 = contextMenu.addAction("Action 2");

            connect(action1, &QAction::triggered, this, [this]() {
                qDebug() << "Action 1 triggered";
            });

            connect(action2, &QAction::triggered, this, [this]() {
                qDebug() << "Action 2 triggered";
            });
            contextMenu.exec(event->screenPos());
        }
    }
};


Probably unrelated, but that aboutToHide connection is a bit suspicious. In fact, you don't really need it: either call deleteLater() right after exec(), or use setAttribute(WA_DeleteOnClose). I'm not sure, as this may not be related, but the problem might be that the deletion of the menu while it's about to hide may cause issues in event targets, so Qt may believe that the mouse grabber is a different one.

@musicamante, yes aboutToHide ended up in my post by accident, these are the remnants of another unsuccessful attempt to solve the problem. I removed it and updated the question.

@musicamante I tried deleteLater() and setAttribute(WA_DeleteOnClose). It did not help.

I see that you're overriding mouse event handlers in the custom item, but that will automatically accept all mouse events, even those you don't manage (which you should ignore instead). Besides, do you really need to do that? If you only need the ability to move the item with the mouse, you should not do it like that, but use setFlag(ItemIsMovable) instead.

@musicamante I tried to remove my mouse movement handlers and use setFlag(ItemIsMovable). A similar problem remains. You can reproduce it if you first move the object, then call up the menu, click on the menu item, then hold down the mouse button in the arbitary location of the GraphicsView and move the mouse. After this, the object will also change position, despite the fact that the mouse was not pressed on it.

Maybe related to this unresolved QTBUG-21943? Try using contextMenu.open() instead of exec(), this may be related to known issues with nested event loops.
